# Как вставить конструкцию HTML в div через цикл?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу реализовать такую логику: если на странице присутствуют теги blockquote, то из них создается массив и затем каждый из элементов этого массива оборачивается в div с классом slider__item и этот div помещается в другой div c id="slider-wrapper". Я попытался сделать это вот так, но это не сработало:

```
let el = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    let blockquoteSliderItem = document.createElement('div');
    blockquoteSliderItem.classList.add('slider__item');
    blockquoteSliderItem.innerHTML = el[i].outerHTML;
    document.getElementById('slider-wrapper').innerHTML = blockquoteSliderItem;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такое решение

```
    const blockquote = document.querySelectorAll("blockquote");

    for (let i = 0; i < blockquote.length; i++) {
      const wrapperBlockQuote = document.createElement("div");

      wrapperBlockQuote.classList.add("slider__item");
      wrapperBlockQuote.appendChild(blockquote[i]);

      document.querySelector("#slider-wrapper").appendChild(wrapperBlockQuote);
    }
```

Comment: appendChild тоже не сработал

Comment: @КонстантинКадочников, что у вас хранится в переменной blockquoteSliderItem?

Comment: <div class="slider__item"><blockquote> <!-- контент blockquote --> </blockquote></div>

Comment: @КонстантинКадочников, попробуйте новое решение

Comment: Попробовал, все заработало, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @КонстантинКадочников, рад помочь